If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x)=c$ for some finite $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0$?

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x)=c$ for some finite $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then is it necessary that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0$?


I tried proof by contradiction, suppose not, then there are these cases

$g$ has a finite limit.
$g$ doesn't have a finite limit but is bounded
$g$ is unbounded.

I am able to prove with epsilon delta definition and the given conditions, however the whole proof is very cumbersome and long, is there a shorter way to prove this assertion? Thanks.

Just write $g(x)=f(x)g(x)\cdot\frac1{f(x)}$ (where $f(x)\neq0$ for large enough $x$).

Look at the definitions.
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$
means that for any $v> 0$
there is a $z(v)$ such that
for all $x > z(v), 
f(x) > v 
$.
Similarly,
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x)=c$
means that
for any $d>0$
there is a $w(d)
$
such that
for all $ x>w(d),
|f(x)g(x)-c|\lt d
$.
To show that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0$
you need to show that
for all $\epsilon >0$
there is a
$u(\epsilon)$ such that
$|g(x)| < \epsilon$
for $x>u(\epsilon)$.
You have to
combine the first two definitions
to produce a
$u(\epsilon)$
in terms of
$z(v)$ and
$w(d)$.

The way suggested in the comments by $g(x)=f(x)g(x)\cdot\frac1{f(x)}$ is very effective and clever.
As an alternative, since $f(x) \to \infty$, by definition
$$\forall M>0 \; \exists x_0 \; \forall x\ge x_0 \; f(x)\ge M$$
then since $f(x)g(x) \to c$, we have $\forall x\ge x_0$ and $\forall \varepsilon_0> 0$
$$|f(x)g(x)-c|\le \varepsilon_0 \iff \frac{c-\varepsilon_0}M\le g(x)\le \frac{c+\varepsilon_0}M$$
and since $M$ is arbitrarly large then $\frac{c\pm \varepsilon_0}M$ can be made arbitrarly small such that for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$ we have $|g(x)|<\varepsilon$ which means, by definition, that $g(x) \to 0$.
